# Angular Date Formatting add the 'at' before time

Tags: angular, date, angular-date-format

Is there simple way to add the word 'at' in between my date and time so it reads like this: Jan 20, 2015 at 11:49 AM, instead of Jan 20, 2015, 11:49 AM. I tried `long` and `full` but I do not want the seconds and locale showing.

```
    2015-01-20 16:49:07+00:00

{{ myDate | date : 'medium' }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can by adding a new `Custom Pipe` or by dealing your `DatePipe (Angular built-in)` in your component

Have attached a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-date-custom-insertion?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your reference

**Method #1 - Custom Pipe**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'dateAtInsert'
})
export class DateAtInsertPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string) {
    return value
      .replace(/,\s(?=\d+:)/g, ' ')
      .split(/\s(?=\d+:)/g)
      .join(' at ');
  }

}
```

```
{{ today | date : dateFormat | datAtInsert }}       // Dec 8, 2020 at 8:26 AM
```

**Method #2 - Date Pipe in Component**

```
const today = new Date();
const transformDate = this.datePipe.transform(today, this.dateFormat);

this.formattedDate = transformDate
   .replace(/,\s(?=\d+:)/g, ' ')
   .split(/\s(?=\d+:)/g)
   .join(' at ');
```

```
<h1>{{ formattedDate }}<h1>             // Dec 8, 2020 at 8:26 AM
```

**Method #3 - Add `at` inside the date format (DatePipe in Component)**

```
dateFormat: string = 'MMM d, y AT h:mm a';        // Need to use an uppercase AT since lowercase "a" is reserved with AM/PM in date formats
                                                  // While capital "A" and "T" doesn't hold any value in date formats so it's safe to use


const transformDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.today, this.dateFormat);

this.formattedDate = transformDate.replace('AT', 'at');
```

**Method #4 - Add `at` inside the date format (DatePipe in HTML)**

*Template*

```
{{ insertDateAt(today | date: 'MMM d, y AT h:mm a') }}
```

*Component*

```
insertDateAt(date: string): string {
  return date.replace('AT', 'at');
}
```

**NOTE:**

- If you want your time to be in format like this `11:49 AM` avoid using `medium` since it includes seconds e.g `11:49:29 AM`
- Use a custom one instead, in our case we used  `MMM d, y, h:mm a` or you can find more formats at [Angular's DatePipe Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: Thanks I decided to just  break them out separately to avoid having to make a custom pipe. I'm not sure if it's bad practice or not: `<span>{{myDate | date: 'MMMM d, y' }} at {{myDate | date: 'h:mm a'}`

Comment: Hi, no problem. I think your solution is good as well, no doubt about that. 
Also, I have updated the answer with Method #3 and #4, just in case. Hope it helps. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thanks and Your Welcome

Comment: Good set of solutions! Unfortunately in my case I need "at" word to be locallized according to the selected language. When using angular pipe with predefined formats `long` or `full`, it is already locallized, but there is now way to include this "at" word when you create custom format :(